# ButterKnife injection issue on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, butterknife

*I can't replicate it* but I've seen this view injection crash affecting about 5-10% of my users through Crashlytics.

The app works fine on everything I throw it at, but some users are definitely not having this experience.

What am I missing? Why would this happen on some devices, but not on others of the same model?

The devices affected include Nexus 4 and Nexus 5. I've tried it on both (Nexus 4 is my main device) without any problems. Also affected are a couple of Samsungs.

Any ideas?

Here's the full stack trace, followed by the *stupidly simple* class and layout xml:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.app/com.package.app.WelcomeActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject views for com.package.app.WelcomeActivity@42b210a8
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject views for com.package.app.WelcomeActivity@42b210a8
          at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:263)
          at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:165)
          at com.package.app.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:30)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view with id '2131296260' for field 'mButtonScores' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Optional' annotation.
          at butterknife.ButterKnife$Finder.findRequiredView(ButterKnife.java:122)
          at com.package.app.WelcomeActivity$$ViewInjector.inject(WelcomeActivity$$ViewInjector.java:12)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
          at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:254)
          at butterknife.ButterKnife.inject(ButterKnife.java:165)
          at com.package.app.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:30)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

### - WelcomeActivity.java

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends FretsActivity {

    private Context mContext;

    @InjectView(R.id.buttonPlay) public Button mButtonPlay;
    @InjectView(R.id.buttonScores) public Button mButtonScores;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        mContext = this;
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        mButtonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        mButtonScores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ScoreActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

### - activity_welcome.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.package.app.screens.WelcomeActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageLogo"
        android:text="Play the Game"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        style="@style/QuizButton"
        android:text="@string/menu_play"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonScores"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/menu_scores"
        style="@style/QuizButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_padding_half"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_padding_half"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nevermind that I could simplify this with @OnClick(1, 2).

Comment: Does the error still happen if you use `@OnClick` instead?

Comment: @fernandohur I can't replicate the issue myself, so while I could try it unfortunately it wouldn't help debug unless I push an update.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the orientation switch. This is my first landscape only app.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any other layout for this activity that has no buttonScores in it?

Comment: @DarthBeleg I definitely don't, however you might be on to something. I *did* have a landscape version that I removed. It could be possible there's still a reference to that in a generated file somewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to force activities into portrait mode even if AndroidManifest forbids it. I tried https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation with your app and got exception that you mentioned.

So I suggest you to review your layouts, may be you forgot some activity_welcome.xml that is loaded in portrait mode and doesn't contain `buttonScores`.

Comment: Of course - lock orientation setting overrides my request for landscape as it should. It's necessary to be able to use the app, but I can make the welcome screen work. Thanks!

Comment: That app replicates the issue, but I'm not sure why the button would be a problem in portrait.